# Data Reader Error in entity framework database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

i am having three database in which it is connected using entity framework to access data from stored procedure first and second databases return 4 columns and third one will return only 3 columns is there any way to handle null or contains in data reader for the 4th column

```
var test = test.TWN_CSS_GetDetails_SP(SearchValue, HDADB, CustCountry,SearchType).ToList<TWN_CSS_GetDetails_SP_Result>();   



public partial class TWN_CSS_GetDetails_SP_Result
{
    public string test1 { get; set; }
    public string test2 { get; set; }
    public string test3 { get; set; }
    public string test4 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: How about sharing some code where we can give you more specific tips? Such as, provide the code what you've reproduced so far to fetch the record(s) and where you want to check for nulls.

Comment: var test = test.TWN_CSS_GetDetails_SP(SearchValue, HDADB, CustCountry,SearchType).ToList<TWN_CSS_GetDetails_SP_Result>();

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it just add another dummy function import and complex types to entity framework once the import is added it adds one extra method in context.cs and then call it like below

```
var test = test.TWN_CSS_GetDetails_SP_dummy(SearchValue, HDADB, CustCountry,SearchType).ToList<TWN_CSS_GetDetails_SP_Dummy_Result>();  

public partial class TWN_CSS_GetDetails_SP_Dummy_Result
{
public string test1 { get; set; }
public string test2 { get; set; }
public string test3 { get; set; }
}
```